# mac mini shuts down seconds after logging in

Tags: macos, startup, mac-mini, shutdown

so as my title says my **Mac mini mid 2010 (Yosemite)** boots up, shows the login screen, I enter my password, then after some seconds it dies. it also happens in safe mode or when I try the Internet recovery mode.

What I already tried:

- Reseting SMC
- Reseting NVRAM
- Repair disk with disk utility
- Checked if the CPU overheats
- Safe boot

I really hope its not a HW problem, any other suggestions? I was only able to google simillar problems where the user stucked in the apple logo booting screen, which is not my case.

I dont have a time machine or any sort of backup and I dont have an access to any other mac os based systems.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: That it happens right after login leads me to *possible* software issue. If you reboot immediately and try again, same thing? Also have you tried a Safe Boot? Hold shift while booting, release shift when you see the Apple logo.

Comment: Yes, same thing

Comment: Maybe I missed this the first time, but if this happens shortly after Recovery Mode, which is a completely different boot method, using none of what is used for normal boot mode, that likely points to a hardware failure. To be sure I would create a bootable image of your current drive, then boot into an installer, wipe the drive and reinstall just the OS (plus Apple updates). If it still happens then I would take it to an Apple Authorized repair tech (Apple store or other trusted tech) and see if they can nail down the problem.

Comment: If by Recovery mode you mean the MacOs Utilities screen, where you can get with (command R) then no, the system doesnt die there, it works. The only recovery mode where it dies is the Interenet Recovery mode, right after it boots up.

Comment: That is recovery mode, both times. Perhaps you should read through this article Apple has about recovery mode. Note that number 5 says "Reinstall macOS: Download and reinstall the Mac operating system." The issue is **exactly  when** it dies. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: Reinstall didnt worked, it has to be the PSU, maybe motherboard